# release memory and the pointer itself? in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, pointers, memory-management

i'm a bit confused, when we release a `pointer` or use `nil` to the pointer, it releases the memory. But what about the pointer itself? it points to an object that does not exist anymore, so is the pointer automatically removed? is it implied that `dealloc` releases both the memory and the pointer itself?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer is a local variable representing an address in memory, not an object. There's nothing to release.

For example:

```
int i = 1;
NSSomething *object = [[NSSomething alloc] init];
```

You now have 2 local variables in the stack, one of type `int` and the other of type `pointer to NSSomething`. You also have a new `NSSomething` instance in the heap. If you simply `return` now, your `i` and `object` variables will go out of scope and disappear, but the `NSSomething` instance in the heap will live on forever. To avoid that, you must `release` (or `autorelease`) it before you `return` from the function.

Comment: thanks Radu, so we might have a pointer that points to nowhere, if we then use this pointer it might crash the app, is this correct? i usually only see the retain/release without using "nil" on the pointers, so i'm wondering if it's a little mistake, or if it's the normal way.

Comment: @Paul, yes, indeed, that's a "defensive programming" technique. If you set the pointer to nil, then the app won't crash if you make a mistake and try to use it, since sending messages to nil does nothing, while sending messages to a released object causes undefined behavior (= random crashes whenever you least expect it, usually after the app is released).

Comment: thanks, should we still be using "nil" in the dealloc? the dealloc is launched when the app stops, so what's the danger?

Answer (score 1):

The pointer still points to the address of the object even though the object has been released. Generally you want to set the pointer to nil or another object after releasing the previous object it had been pointing to. If you are using objective-c properties the pointer connected to the property is automatically set to nil.

Comment: thanks, could we just use `nil` with the setter, instead of `release`, so that the setter takes care of releasing the object and passes the pointer to nil ? in the few examples i've read so far, i've only seen the use of "release" but not much "nil" with the setter

Comment: I still release the object then set the property to nil, but know days I would just recommend using ARC

Answer (score 0):

The pointer itself is wiped by the stack frame on return (kinda like the assembly call RET, more like the stack braces { } which actually open { and close } a stack frame).

Nothing for you to worry about when it comes to the pointers themselves. If you really wanted to, you could assign the pointer (cast as void *) and set it NULL after setting id * as nil. (Setting NULL right away causes a bad access error when an objective-c message is passed).